what URL should Kestrel listen to in a docker container on Azure App Service
I have an ASP.NET Core in a docker container that will be hosted on Azure App Service. What URL should I have Kestrel, which is inside the container, listen on when deploying to Azure App Service?
My mental model is I could use localhost:8080, then bind that container port 8080 to port 443 of Azure App Service via -p 443:8080. So when visiting https://myapp.azurewebsites.net, that 443 will be forwarded to 8080 that Kestrel is listening to.
ChatGPT suggested to listen to wildcard 0.0.0.0, but my gut feeling of both localhost and 0.0.0.0 are wrong
So what is the correct way to do? Thank you. I am self-taught and I only have very basic networking knowledge so please explain like I'm 5, and give keywords so that I could research more. Thank you

You definitely want to bind to (that's what it's called) 0.0.0.0. It specifies where you'll accept connections from. In a container, localhost is the container itself, so if you bind to localhost, your application will only accept connections coming from inside the container. That's not what you want.
As for what port to use inside the container, it doesn't really matter as you'll map it to a host port when you run the container. The aspnet images from Microsoft are configured to accept HTTP traffic on port 8080 for .NET 8 and on port 80 for .NET 7 and earlier.
Since you map to host port 443 it looks like you want to use HTTPS and not HTTP. To do that, you need to configure ASP to do that, as the default is HTTP only. You can configure ASP by setting the environment variable ASPNETCORE_URLS to something like https://+:8443. Then it'll listen for HTTPS on port 8443. If you do this, I recommend listening on another port than 8080 since that's conventionally used for HTTP traffic.
To use HTTPS you also need to configure certificates. You can read more about it here.
Short answer: To get a .NET 8 aspnet container up and running, this command should do the trick:
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development my-image

The environment needs to be set to Development if you want Swagger to be available. Swagger is only available in the Development environment and the default is that a docker container is not development.

very appreciate your detailed answer. I'd like to follow up: Exactly which network interface or IP address is the gateway into the container? In order word, when a GET request goes to the provided azure app service public url, https://myapp.azurewebsites.net port 443, and forwarded to port 8443 of the container, which IP address of the container will receive that request? 0.0.0.0 would listen to all network interface, but which network interface actually receive the request forwarded from azure app service?

I'm not that familiar with Azure. But in a Docker setup, the container is normally connected to a docker bridge network and given an IP address on that network. So what the port mapping does is take the traffic on the host port and forward it to the container on the bridge network and the mapped container port. As for which interface the traffic comes in on, I just tried spinning up a debian container and it comes in on the eth0 interface.

that's very interesting. So in brief, I should set Kestrel to listen on a wildcard of network interface, i.e. 0.0.0.0, to catch all incoming traffic forwarded into the container right? Would there be any security concern for production? In other word, seems like people don't really care which network interface the container receive the traffic from, they only care about the port. Am I correct? Also which command did you run to find out the container listened on eth0?

Yes, that's correct. The MS default for the .NET containers is to bind to 0.0.0.0, so I believe that it's safe. What you can do, on the host side, is bind to localhost, so the mapped port only will accept traffic coming from the host machine itself. You can do that by binding to 127.0.0.1 on the port mapping, so you'll have -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080. But inside the container, you still bind to 0.0.0.0. You might want to do that if you don't expect traffic from outside the host machine.

appreciate your help. I will give this a try!
